# Ionic 2 inappbrowser how to go back to app from browser on success

Tags: ionic2, inappbrowser

I have an app where I need to open the webview on checkout.Till this section everything is working fine but after successful completion of order I have to close the browser by matching the url and show the app again.
Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
I have tried but hard luck I am not able to closed the browser by url detection.

Thank you,
Shreya

Comment: Have you tried  window.open(url, '_self') ?

Comment: can you share the code ? so that we can have look at first !

Comment: I did  let browser = this.iab.create('http://10.10.1.49/travcompare/index.php/checkout/onepage?mob=1&customer_id='+this.cust_id, '_blank',{location:'no'}); to open in browser. And after that I am unable to close on successful checkout from browser.